# CSS multiple spaces inside span element

Tags: html, css, jsp, jstl, whitespace

I have a page where I am trying to display full name (firstName lastName) on the browser.

In my JSP, I have

```
<span>
    <c:if test="${someCondition1}">
        <c:out value="${firstName}">
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${someCondition2}">
        <c:out value="${lastName}">
    </c:if>
</span>
```

Now there are some code indentation spaces inside the span element. 
The issue is that in Firefox, the code spaces are not collapsed, while IE collapses them.

Also I tried using the various CSS white-space properties ;normal, wrap, -moz-pre-wrap, etc

But this does not seem to be working for some reason.

Also I might not be able to use the white-space property to fix this, since I can have multiple spaces within the firstName/lastName as well which should be displayed as it is e.g. first Name can be

```
"my    First   Name"
```

Thus using CSS white-space on the span element to collapse multiple spaces would be wrong.

Comment: mh... do you want the spaces or do you want to remove them?

Comment: I want code spaces to be removed (i.e. outside of c:out) and spaces within fname/lname to be retained (i.e. what c:out returns)

Comment: *The issue is that in Firefox, the code spaces are not collapsed, while IE collapses them.* This is not true for the code given so far. Are you talking about the rendered output as you see in browser's viewport, or are you talking about the generated HTML source as you see in browser's "View Source" tool? If it's the former, please post an SSCCE. If it's the latter, then it's the tool itself who's has collapsed it for you.

Comment: I am referrring to spaces in the generated source of the page (and not really the rendered browser output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace your spaces with `&nbsp;`

```
firstName = firstName.replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
```

With this you don't need your CSS `white-space` anymore.

Comment: It would help if you want to add space, but you don't. Didn't know that when I was writing this.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox *should* be collapsing the spaces but if not try `white-space-collapse: collapse;`. This is a CSS3 property that explicitly gives the behaviour you want.

EDIT: Wait, I'm confused. In what scenario would it ever be reasonable to use more than 1 space between parts of a name? I'm not aware of any human language where that is acceptable. Is this some kind of alien language?

Comment: I want code spaces to be removed (i.e. outside of c:out) and spaces within fname/lname to be retained (i.e. what c:out returns)....So yes, though sounds odd, I can have spaces within the name...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<span><c:out value="${someCondition1?firstName:''} ${someCondition2?lastName:''}"/></span>
```

have everything in single line.

Comment: Thx for that...Actually having the entire code in one line works even with what I have....But I want to fix this more generically, where different developers who could use different code indentations and it should still work fine...